# Self-transfer at Istanbul Airport

Tags: international-travel, uk-citizens, self-transfer, ist

I’ve been looking everywhere, however I have been unable to find an answer to this.

On Thursday I arrive into Istanbul (IST) at 17.45 (BA) and my next flight is on Flyadeal at 21.35.

I already have a mobile boarding pass for my next flight and I have only got cabin bags.

Can I use the international transfers point at IST or do I still need to enter the country?

Comment: Note that while you I’ll probably be able to stay airside (I’m not familiar with IST hence the comment and not answer), BA will likely ask for proof that you can enter Turkey (as, for them, this is your final destination). The documentation required (visa, e-Visa, or just passport) will depend on your citizenship.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I use the International Transfers point at IST

Most likely the answer is "yes". IST has a single security check point that all connecting passengers are funnelled through, which appears to feed all international departure gates.

Just follow the red signs like these:

[image]

However, this is never guaranteed, so it'll be a mistake to rely on it.

NOTE: Regardless of whether you can stay in the sterile transit area or not, you **MUST** have full credentials to enter Turkey. Otherwise BA will not let you board the flight and you won't make it to IST In the first place. So you MUST be able to enter Turkey even if you have no intention to do so.

Comment: Hi there @Hilmar I have a UK Passport so entering isn't an issue, However I'll try my best not to because of time constraints. I have around 4 hrs. So I'm not overly concerned. But I'm just trying to pre-plan my options so I'm not standing at the airport confused on what to do. Using the transit point is my Plan A

Comment: @AffanAbdurehmanButt : that's fine then. Just follow the red signs to "International Transfers" .